# Wordpress: Add row to ACF through the backend when creating a post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm kinda new to wordpress, I'm using advanced custom fields(with repeater) and custom post types UI plugins, this might be a bit confusing but this is what I've been stuck in a while:

I have a post type with 5 fields, 4 normal fields and 1 repeater, I want to add specific information to the first 4 regular fields and after pressing publish, to have the repeater add rows of information until I end up with the table needed.

```
for example, my 4 fields could be:
-Current amount(number)
-Date to start off(Date picker)
-Amount of months it will carry on(number) //each month will have a row
-Percent of Interest given each month(number)
```

After adding this information, I'd like to have the rows be generated In my 5th field which is a repeater, So if I, lets say, added this info:

```
-Current amount: 500
-Date to start off September: 2014
-Amount of months it will carry on: 3
-Percent of Interest given each month: 10%
```

To have the repeater show this table:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x    Date    x  Amount  x Interest added x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x Sept 2014  x   500    x       50       x
x Oct 2014   x   550    x       55       x
x Nov 2014   x   605    x      60.5      x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

It's Important to be able to view the information in the repeater in wordpress, and I found information about how to add info programmatically like this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152995/programmatically-add-acf-repeater-row-in-specific-order-position
But in that example, the user does this by using an interface on the front end, I must be able to do the same but while the admin is modifing the custom post in the backend, so basiclly I have no idea where to add my code.

Where should I place all my code?

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress Hierarchy is something like this:

```
wp
-wp-admin
-wp-content
--index.php
--plugins
--themes
--upgrade
--uploads
-wp-includes
-index.php
-wp-activate.php
-wp-login.php
```

most of what you want to do is likely in the wp-content folder. Under themes there is also a folder for templates. this is likely where you want to do this.

Comment: Well, maybe but where

Comment: the best method is to create a child theme of one of the themes already listed in the themes folder. Once you do that, look for the index.php, functions.php, header.php maybe sidebar.php? The index page calls these various functions and files to create the overall page, so it depends on your theme. some have multiple sidebars, usually appended by sidebar_yoursidebarcontent.php and the appended php file is added to the general sidebar.php function. ... again, take a look at the theme you are using, and look at what the index.php file calls. If that isn't helpful, look at the default template